# How To Make react-native-banner-carousel Horizontal Scroll Disable?

Tags: react-native, carousel, banner

using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-banner-carousel) to make some carousel in my project, been searching a while but no luck, how can I make the horizontal scroll disable? Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to disable the horizontal scroll? how the users should change presented image?

Comment: I'm using the carousel because I'm using the index feature on that package for another purpose. For example, I've some items on my dropdown let's say string1, string2, and string3, if I choose "string1" from a dropdown on the app bar, the carousel will show the string1's carousel only, if I choose "string2", and it will show the string2's carousel only @D10S

Comment: oh.. so you to disable the scrolling of this specific package

Comment: yes I do, because that't the only way I knew to do that

Comment: I see. Maybe try to place a transparent view over the carousel. That should do the trick.

Comment: this package not support passing props to the Flatlist, so try adding `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={ (evt, gestureState) => true}` to it's container

Comment: Great, it disabled the scroll, but I can't click the carousel now @Horst

Comment: Oops, then change it to `onMoveShouldSetResponder`

Comment: Great solution! That trick is worked! Thanks! @Horst

Comment: Then please answer your question with your study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As by [Horst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1873027/horst)'s comment,

Using onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture={ (evt, gestureState) => true} solved the problem